# I can't get the id in the view

Tags: angular, typescript

We have two classes "demande" and "entreprise" with a relation `OneToMany`. I would like to show every demande's entreprise.

The API works but the problem is on the front.

The entreprise's service :

```js
getDemandeEntreprisebyId(id)
  {
    this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/Entreprise/EntrepriseByDemande/'+id)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => this.listDemandeEntreprise = res as Entreprise[]);
  }
```

View :

```html
<tr *ngFor="let sd of serviceDemande.list" >
  <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.dateDemande | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
  <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.typeDemande}}</td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  <td  *ngFor="let e of serviceEntreprise.getDemandeEntreprisebyId(sd.idDemande)">{{e.nomEntreprise}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to return the data from the service (i.e., `return this.http.get`...).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm novice, I have not understand your explication. Can you explain more please ?
Thank you

Comment: Put your cursor in front of the first letter after the `{` in the `getDemandeEnterprisebyId` function. Type `return` and a space. See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: what are you getting in the sd.idDemande ?. have you checked the value with the debugger or using console.log? in getDemandeEntreprisebyId function ?